# pthread_cond_timedwait()

Tags: c, pthreads

```
void wait(int timeInMs)
{
    struct timespec timeToWait;
    timeToWait.tv_sec = 5;
    timeToWait.tv_nsec = timeInMs*1000;

    int rt;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&fakeMutex);
    rt = pthread_cond_timedwait(&fakeCond, &fakeMutex, &timeToWait);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&fakeMutex);
}
```

I'm using this code to try to get a thread to wait around for a bit, but it doesn't work at all.  No errors, it just doesn't make the program execute any slower.

I was thinking maybe each thread needs to have it's own condition and mutex, but that really doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It doesn't matter for this example, but nsec = 1,000,000 * msec.

Answer (score 20):

The `pthread_cond_timedwait` function takes an *absolute* time, not a relative time. It takes the time you want to stop waiting, not how long you want to wait.

Answer (score 19):

Using any variant of sleep, the behavior is not guaranteed. All the threads can also sleep since the kernel is not aware of the different threads.

A safer and cleaner solution to use is `pthread_cond_timedwait`. You used the API incorrectly. Here is a better example:

```
pthread_mutex_t fakeMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t fakeCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void mywait(int timeInMs)
{
    struct timespec timeToWait;
    struct timeval now;
    int rt;

    gettimeofday(&now,NULL);


    timeToWait.tv_sec = now.tv_sec+5;
    timeToWait.tv_nsec = (now.tv_usec+1000UL*timeInMs)*1000UL;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&fakeMutex);
    rt = pthread_cond_timedwait(&fakeCond, &fakeMutex, &timeToWait);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&fakeMutex);
    printf("\nDone\n");
}

void* fun(void* arg)
{
    printf("\nIn thread\n");
    mywait(1000);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    void *ret;

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, fun, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread,&ret);
}
```

You need to specify how much time to wait from current time. Since you were only telling 5 sec and some nano-seconds it found that the time had already passed and did not wait...Please let me know if any more doubts.

Comment: For me, gettimeofday(&now,NULL) didn't work, but this did (for 200ms): clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timeToWait);
 timeToWait.tv_nsec += 200000000UL;
 timeToWait.tv_nsec %= 1000000000UL;
 timeToWait.tv_sec += timeToWait.tv_nsec < 200000000UL ? 1 : 0;

Comment: `timeToWait` seemingly suggests relative time.  For it to hint at an absolute timestamp, it should be refactored as `waitUntil`.

Answer (score 10):

pthread_cond_timedwait uses absolute time, so need to:

- use gettimeofday to retrieve current time.
- timespec.tv_nsec is nanosecond, it can't be large than 1 second.
- timeval.tv_usec is microsecond (1000 nanoseconds).
- timeInMs is millisecond: 1 millisecond = 1000 microseconds = 1000 * 1000 nanoseconds.

  ```
  void wait(int timeInMs)
  {
      struct timeval tv;
      struct timespec ts;

      gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
      ts.tv_sec = time(NULL) + timeInMs / 1000;
      ts.tv_nsec = tv.tv_usec * 1000 + 1000 * 1000 * (timeInMs % 1000);
      ts.tv_sec += ts.tv_nsec / (1000 * 1000 * 1000);
      ts.tv_nsec %= (1000 * 1000 * 1000);

      int n = pthread_cond_timedwait(&condition, &mutex, &ts);
      if (n == 0)
          // TODO: singaled
      else if (n == ETIMEDOUT)
          // TODO: Time out.
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Considering you are using timespec, and your goal isn't to synchronize but to wait I'd suggest nanosleep.

```
#include <time.h>

.
.
.

  struct timespec remain;
  remain.tv_sec = 5;
  remain.tv_nsec = timeInMs * 1000;

  do {
    if ( nanosleep( &remain, &remain ) == 0 || errno != EINTR ) {
      break;
    }
  } while ( 1 );

.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3):

Main reference: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html

**FIX of the code of [andrewrk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432/andrewrk) above**

I can confirm [Adrian May](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2910747/adrian-may) that gettimeofday doesn't function correctly! 
The code behavior of [andrewrk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432/andrewrk) inside an infinite thread like this

```
static void * thread_infinite(void * unused) {
while (1) {
        // compute stuff
        mywait(5);
}
```

is unpredictable: it runs approximate 700 times more until it blocks!

The correct version of the code of [andrewrk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432/andrewrk) is:

```
pthread_mutex_t fakeMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t fakeCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void mywait(int timeInS)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    struct timeval now;
    int rt = 0;

//    gettimeofday(&now,NULL); // DOES NOT FUNCTION CORRECTLY
//    timeToWait.tv_sec = now.tv_sec+5;
//    timeToWait.tv_nsec = (now.tv_usec+1000UL*timeInMs)*1000UL;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
    ts.tv_sec += timeInS;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&fakeMutex);

    do {
        rt = pthread_cond_timedwait(&fakeCond, &fakeMutex, &ts);
        }
    while (rt == 0);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&fakeMutex);
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked and it was good that you fixed the post with the most upvotes.

Comment: thank you @JohnJesus for testing and confirming!

Answer (score 2):

That code doesn't sleep, it checks a condition for a while. As you are not probably setting cond ok it just returns immediately.

If you are not willing to synchronize threads around a signal then pthread_cond _wait is not what you need. Check [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) how condition variables work.

if you want to sleep with seconds precision use [sleep](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/Sleep/)

If you want to sleep with microseconds precision use [select](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-6.html) with timevals.

Comment: but sleep stops an entire process, I need the thread to wait.

Comment: Use "select" with a timeval and NULL for the read, write, exception parameters. Note that using select this way only works on linux, in windows select returns immediately if only a timeval parameter is provided

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where I have created a thread from main loop which does a scan of a directory and have a timeout of 5 sec. And signalling from the thread happens using a conditional variable which is a global. We keep checking for this signal from thread:

```
    pthread_cond_t C_KISU_SwagntUtilityBase::m_cond; /*Global variable*/
/*Inside main function*/    
/*Local variables*/
          pthread_condattr_t l_attr;
          pthread_condattr_init(&l_attr);
          pthread_condattr_setclock(&l_attr, CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
          pthread_cond_init(&C_KISU_SwagntUtilityBase::m_cond, &l_attr);

          Int32 l_threadid = pthread_create(&l_updatethread,NULL,C_KISU_SwagntUtilityBase::ThreadScanDirectoryByFilter,&l_filer);
          if(CMP_ZERO == l_threadid)
          {
            pthread_mutex_t l_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
            struct timespec l_ts;
            if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &l_ts) == INIT_NEGONE)
            {
             /* Handle error */
            }
            printf("\n Setting max time to  run ThreadScanDirectoryByFilter as 5 second"));
            l_ts.tv_sec += l_filer.m_max_scan_time;

            if(l_filer.m_scan_status == 0)
            {
              pthread_mutex_lock(&l_mutex);
              int l_rt = pthread_cond_timedwait(&C_KISU_SwagntUtilityBase::m_cond, &l_mutex, &l_ts);
              if (ETIMEDOUT == l_rt)
              {
                printf("\n timeout has happened before scan routine could finish"));
              }
              else if (EOK  == l_rt)
              {
                printf("\n Scan successful"));
              }
              else
              {
                printf("\n Unknown error while timeout condition check"));
              }
              pthread_mutex_unlock(&l_mutex);
            }
          }
          else
          {
            printf("\n Error while creating thread\n");

          }
```