# Break while time events

Tags: c++

I need help.
I am writing the following code:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point end_time =
  std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(T);

while( end_time > std::chrono::system_clock::now() ){
  pthread_cond_wait(&dcond_var, &mutex);
  //do work
}
```

So I need a control loop and that lasts a certain period of time and I need that the operations inside the control loops are synchronized by a conditional variable. The problem is that the wait on conditional variable sometimes make the control loop last more than the needed T seconds.
Is there a method to break the while after exactly T seconds even if the system is waiting on pthread_cond_wait?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pthread\_cond\_timedwait() help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486833/pthread-cond-timedwait-help)

Comment: Why not use `std::condition_variable` which has a `wait_until` member that takes a `chrono::time_point`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like `pthread_cond_timedwait` or another mutex function where you can set a timeout. The timeout would be `end_time - now`. If `pthread_cond_timedwait` returns `ETIMEDOUT` means that the timeout has passed and you don't have to do the work.